# Lodash groupBy order

Tags: arrays, collections, lodash

I am sorting array by date and then groupBy date but after that first object is 2016 year.

```
let array = [{date: "2017-06-01", name: 'some'},{date:"2017-05-27",  name: 'someElse'},{date:"2016-12-24", name: 'something'}];
let _data = _.groupBy(array, function(item) {
            return item.date.substring(0,4);
        });
```

And that output

```
{2016: [], 2017: []}
```

And I need

```
{2017: [], 2016: []}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result is a JavaScript object with two properties, `2016` and `2017`. It is not an array (which are ordered), but an object, whose properties are unordered by design.

You can iterate through them in order by doing something like `_.keys(x).sort().reverse().map(...)`

Comment: thank you that helps me to write new loop to render 2017 first

Comment: Since ES2015, object properties _are_ ordered by design, though as far as I can tell from the documentation, lodash doesn't guarantee the order of properties in the result of groupBy